# Why am i stuck at a certain resolution?

Tags: xorg, xrandr, resolution

I've got a DELL Inspiron 6400 and i use Ubuntu 11.04, when I connect my TV screen via VGA it only works at a 1024x768. It worked fine in 10.10 at the full resolution 1360x768.

I've tried lots of steps but nothing worked, the resolution just won't change to 1360x768. If anybody can tell me what to do step by step i would appreciate.
Sometimes it says it can't find the desire mode.

Comment: As you have mentioned, it doesn't find the mode you want, what have you tried?.

Comment: iv tried adding new modes., but doest work... iv tried the xrandr commands to fix it and to add modes. etc etc

Answer (score 6):

Issue `xrandr` on the console will show you the names of different outputs available on your system (LVDS, VGA-0, etc.) and resolutions available on each:

If you see the desired resolutions available for the output that you want (tv screen), set it via `xrandr --output <output> --mode <mode>` (example: `xrandr --output LVDS --mode 1360x768`)

If your desired resolution is not available, following the following example (example showing 800 600 but you should be able to do the same for 1360 768).

```
$ cvt 800 600
# 800x600 59.86 Hz (CVT 0.48M3) hsync: 37.35 kHz; pclk: 38.25 MHz
Modeline "800x600_60.00" 38.25 800 832 912 1024 600 603 607 624 -hsync +vsync

$ xrandr --newmode "800x600" 38.25 800 832 912 1024 600 603 607 624 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --addmode LVDS 800x600
$ xrandr --output LVDS --mode 800x600
```

Taken from [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr).

Comment: This is an excellent diagnostic step. If you can get the correct resolution with `xrandr`, then it is definitely a software problem, not a hardware problem.

Comment: i just get a full resolution before with the same tv a pc... can you send me the commands for my case couse im an amaeur at this things

Comment: i tried what you answered back but dindt work

Comment: it says that cannot find mode 1360x768

Comment: Sorry, made a little bit to the xrandr --newmode , please try again.

Comment: it keep's saying xrandr cannot find mode 1360x768